# Use Tippy.js in Angular

Tags: angular, tippyjs

I have a directive with the following code

```
import { Directive, Input, OnInit, ElementRef, SimpleChanges, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import tippy from 'tippy.js';

@Directive({
  selector: '[tippy]'
})
export class TippyDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input('tippyOptions') public tippyOptions: Object;

  private el: any;
  private tippy: any = null;
  private popper: any = null;

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.el = el;
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.loadTippy();
  }

  public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.tippyOptions) {
      this.tippyOptions = changes.tippyOptions.currentValue;
      this.loadTippy();
    }
  }

  public tippyClose() {
    this.loadTippy();
  }

  private loadTippy() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let el = this.el.nativeElement;
      let tippyOptions = this.tippyOptions || {};

      if (this.tippy) {
        this.tippy.destroyAll(this.popper);
      }

      this.tippy = tippy(el, tippyOptions, true);
      this.popper = this.tippy.getPopperElement(el);
    });
  }
}
```

And using the directive as follows

```
<input tippy [tippyOptions]="{
              arrow: true,
              createPopperInstanceOnInit: true
            }" class="search-input" type="text" 
(keyup)="searchInputKeyDown($event)">
```

How can I have the Tippy shown on mouseenter or focus as these are the default triggers, from the tippy instance I have in the directive, this is what I get when I put `console.log(this.tippy)` on line 44

```
{
  destroyAll:ƒ destroyAll()
  options:{placement: "top", livePlacement: true, trigger: "mouseenter focus", animation: "shift-away", html: false, …}
  selector:input.search-input
  tooltips:[]
}
```

As I am getting an error when I try to use

```
this.popper = this.tippy.getPopperElement(el);

ERROR TypeError: _this.tippy.getPopperElement is not a function
```

How can I get this directive to work as I took it from a repo in github

```
https://github.com/tdanielcox/ngx-tippy/blob/master/lib/tippy.directive.ts
```

What is it that I am missing here, any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure what they were trying to accomplish in the linked repo you have included. To get `tippy.js` to work though, you should be able to change the directive to the following:

```
import { Directive, Input, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import tippy from 'tippy.js';

@Directive({
  /* tslint:disable-next-line */
  selector: '[tippy]'
})
export class TippyDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input('tippyOptions') public tippyOptions: Object;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.el = el;
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    tippy(this.el.nativeElement, this.tippyOptions || {}, true);
  }
}
```

[Working example repo](https://github.com/PdUi/stack-overflow-answer-repos/tree/master/ng-tippy)

Comment: Hey.. okay let me try that

Comment: Hey @peinearydevelopment, Man!!! They say never give up, I can't believe this!
I have been trying to get it to work the whole day, I even went out to grab some cold drinks just to cool down, now I came back and now this transpires!, thanks so much, I really appreciate your help :D

Comment: Pleasure, glad it helped you. Looking in the tippy.js file, there wasn't anything in there called `getPopperElement`, so I'm not entirely sure what they were trying to do with that.

Comment: @gotnull Refer to the referenced repo, specifically https://github.com/PdUi/stack-overflow-answer-repos/blob/master/ng-tippy/angular.json line 27

Answer (score 6):

This works with tippy.js 6.x

```js
@Directive({selector: '[tooltip],[tooltipOptions]'})
export class TooltipDirective implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, OnChanges {
  constructor(private readonly el: ElementRef) {}

  private instance: Instance<Props> = null;

  @Input() tooltip: string;
  @Input() tooltipOptions: Partial<Props>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.instance = tippy(this.el.nativeElement as Element, {});
    this.updateProps({
      ...(this.tooltipOptions ?? {}),
      content: this.tooltip,
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.instance?.destroy();
    this.instance = null;
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    let props = {
      ...(this.tooltipOptions ?? {}),
      content: this.tooltip,
    };

    if (changes.tooltipOptions) {
      props = {...(changes.tooltipOptions.currentValue ?? {}), content: this.tooltip};
    }
    if (changes.tooltip) {
      props.content = changes.tooltip.currentValue;
    }

    this.updateProps(props);
  }

  private updateProps(props: Partial<Props>) {
    if (this.instance && !jsonEqual<any>(props, this.instance.props)) {
      this.instance.setProps(this.normalizeOptions(props));
      if (!props.content) {
        this.instance.disable();
      } else {
        this.instance.enable();
      }
    }
  }

  private normalizeOptions = (props: Partial<Props>): Partial<Props> => ({
    ...(props || {}),
    duration: props?.duration ?? [50, 50],
  });
}
```

Using this looks like:

```html
<button [tooltip]="'Hello!'">Hover here</button>
<button [tooltip]="'Hi!'" [tooltipOptions]="{placement: 'left'}">Hover here</button>
```

Comment: Nice directive @alex-rempel . Would you mind explaining what `jsonEqual` is because I am not familiar with it?

Comment: jsonEqual is any implementation where you compare items on JSON level e.g. for typescript something like:

```ts

export const jsonEqual = <T>(aa: T, bb: T): boolean => JSON.stringify(aa) === JSON.stringify(bb);
```

Comment: Underrated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the lifecyle hook ngAfterViewInit then you don't need the setTimeout.

```
public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadTippy();
}
```